# Sonarqube: Php equivalent annotation for ignoring sonarqube rule

Tags: sonarqube

I know that in Java, we can ignore the a Sonarqube rule for specific method with annotations. For example...

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2078")
```

With php, I have not narrowed down how to do this yet. Is there an equivalent example that ignores **one** rule for a specific piece of code (not necessarily for a class/function, but it would be a start :) )

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but you can suppress warnings when calling a particular function in PHP by adding an `@` symbol before it. E.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 3):

The current version of php analyser (SonarPhp 2.14 in SonarQube 7.3) does **not** have a feature (annotation based or not) for ignoring a specific rule.

The php analyser only support one issue filtering, the NoSonarFilter that disable all rules at a specific line by using a comment containing `NOSONAR`.

If a rule generate some false positives, or if you are facing a real life example where such filter is require, you can provide some feedback at [community.sonarsource.com](https://community.sonarsource.com/)

Comment: Is this still case today?